# Domino V10 and POI

Tags: apache-poi, lotus-domino

I tried to install new Domino V10 on my test server and then added POI Plugin. It seems everything works great but when tried to create/export an excel file via POI this line does not work. Does poi work with Domino V10 or not? Any suggestion would be great.

```
**var wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);**

//POI CODE SAMPLE
var resourcePath = "/DemoExcel.xlsx";
var excelName = "DepoExcel_v1.xslx";
var bantfile = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
var excelFilePath = bantfile+"\\"+ excelName;
var inp = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
var wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
var sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
//Code continuous here...
```

UPDATE 2:
ERROR LOG DETAILS 
`CLFAD0141E: Error processing XPage request CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown` 
 `CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for:  /ays/poi.nsf/xspViewMainPage.xsp - HTTP Code: 500'`

Comment: You need to give more detail then "does not work".  Tell us exactly what happens. Does it throw an error? If so, what is the exact error, and what line of code throws the error?

Comment: I have new Windows Server 2012 Server and then I have installed Domino V9.01 I mean the same version of Domino as installed to my old server. I copied UpdatesSite.nsf to new server also, names.nsf and notes.ini (All necessary config files)  in order to have the same configuration. Everything works fine except POI. I have checked log files. Please see the error lines below. I have no idea where to start to dig...
CLFAD0141E: Error processing XPage request   
CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown   
CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /ays/poinsf/xspViewMainPage.xsp - HTTP Code: 500

Comment: var wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
this line of code  throws the error.